# How can I get an ObjectInputStream that supports mark/reset?

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I'm trying to get an `ObjectInputStream` that will allow me to read data from it and, if it's not of the right type, put the data back onto the stream (using `mark` and `reset`) for some other code to deal with. I've tried wrapping the `InputStream` retrieved from the `Socket` (`s` in the following example) in a `BufferedInputStream` before wrapping it in an `ObjectInputStream` as I believed to be the solution, however when calling `ois.markSupported()` false is still returned. Below is that attempt:

```
ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is `s.getInputStream()` created?

Comment: Why don't you make the 'other code' deal with the object that has been read rather than the input stream.

Comment: @JohnnyV `s` is of type `Socket` and is created using a `ServerSocket` and subsequently calling `s.accept()` to create the connection.

Comment: @rodit I'm using multiple threads, so sending it across would be more trouble than it's worth I believe when I could just push it back onto the stream until the other thread gets a chance to read it.

Comment: @HarveyAdcock I see.

Comment: Multiple threads reading from a socket is never ever going to work. Reconsider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would build a higher-level abstraction on top of the stream. Something like this (pseudo-code, not finalized):

```
public class Buffer {
    private final ObjectInputStream in;

    private Object current;

    public Buffer(ObjectInputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public Object peek() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = in.readObject();
        }
        return current;
    }

    public void next() {
        current = in.readObject();
    }
}
```

You would use peek() repeatedly to get the current object, and if it suits you, call next() to go to the next one.

Of course, you need to deal with exceptions, the end of the stream, closing it properly, etc. But you should get the idea.

Or, if you can just read everything in memory, then do it and create a Queue with the objects from the stream, then pass that Queue around and use `peek()` and `poll()`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be some implementation already in the number of different `InputStream` subclasses, but I guess not. Maybe I don't know enough, but I find it weird that since the actual `InputStream` type passed to the `ObjectInputStream` supports mark and reset that the `ObjectInputStream` itself would support it. So essentially the `BufferedObjectStream` could call its `InputStream`'s `markSupported()` method instead of just returning false, do you know why this isn't the case?

Comment: An ObjectInputStream is a stateful stream, that needs to keep references to objects it has already read in order not to recreate them if they're referenced by future objects of the stream. I suspect goind backwards is not obvious.