# ObjectOutputStream is causing memory leak and reset() throws error

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

This problem really has me stumped. I'm sending images from a client to a server using `ObjectOutputStream`, but over time the java heap keeps growing. This eventually causes an `OutOfMemoryError` exception. After some online research, the reset method seems to be the only solution. Which is great, but using it causes an error: mark/reset not supported. The only page I could find on this was here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814424/how-can-i-get-an-objectinputstream-that-supports-mark-reset

I'm not really sure what to do with that page's answer.

Anyway, here's the server code:

```
ServerSocket vchatserver = new ServerSocket(6677);
Socket c1 = vchatserver.accept();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(c1.getInputStream()); 
while(c1.isConnected()) {
    ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) ois.readUnshared();
    ois.reset();
}
```

And now the client's code:

```
Socket vchatclient = new Socket(pub_serverName, 6677);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(vchatclient.getOutputStream());
while(vchatclient.isConnected()) {
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(webcam.getImage());
    oos.writeUnshared(img);
    oos.reset();        
    Thread.sleep(25);
}
```

Comment: Slightly off topic but the `try-with-resources` syntax added in java 7 significantly helps combat memory leaks. I highly recommend it: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object *input* stream doesn't support mark/reset. But you don't need it. You don't need to call `reset()` on the input stream. `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` is sufficient.

The question you linked is irrelevant.

NB `while (c1.isConnected())` is not a valid test for end of stream. You need to catch `EOFException`. Similarly `while (vchatclient.isConnected())` will not protect you from `IOExceptions` when writing. This method only tells you whether you have ever connected *this socket*. It doesn't tell you anything about the current state of the *connection*.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. But, ObjectOutputStream.reset() is giving me an error:non-static method reset() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` is the name of the method. It is written that way so the reader knows what I'm talking about: as opposed to `ObjectInputStream.reset()`, which isn't supported.  You were already calling it correctly, via a reference. Surely this is all obvious?

Comment: Ok, so all I need to do is remove the reset() for the ObjectInputStream? Also, I just noticed you edited the first part of your response. Even with writeUnshared I'm getting a memory leak.

Comment: Correct. `writeUnshared()` does't work because `ImageIcon` has several fields I hadn't thought of, such as its own URL, and fields are not written with `writeUnshared()`, so they leak.